# How can I track how embedded media is used across my site?

Tags: nodes, media

My site uses the core Media module, [Entity Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed), and [LinkIt](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) to reference media and other entities in various ways.

I want to keep track of which media is embedded on which nodes.

I tried adding an entity reference field to media on my content types, but this means that I have to add the media twice: to the field where I actually embed the media and to the entity reference field to track it.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a [core issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2835840) to eventually get this into core.

Now, the best way is to use the [Entity Usage](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_usage) module, which can handle tracking of media and many other cases.

Hats off to the module maintainers-- this is all I needed to do to implement my use case:

1. Download the module with composer.
2. Enable the module.
3. Go to `/admin/config/entity-usage/settings` and check **Media** under **Enabled local tasks**.